# Show that the infinite arithmetic progression $<1,4,7,10...>$ has infinitely many 3 term subsequences in harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

If $a,b,c$ are in hp then $\dfrac{2ac}{a+c}=b$

Let the 3 term subsequence be

$ 3m+1,3n+1,3p+1 $

Substituting in above formula yields

$6pm-3mn-3pn+m+p -2n = 0$

Then what to do further?? QUESTION further asks to prove(not included in title)

that for any two such triples $<a_1,a_2,a_3>$ and $<b_1,b_2,b_3>$ in harmonic progression one has $\frac{a_1}{b_1}\not = \frac{a_2}{b_2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $m\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, let $n=2m$ and $p=6m^2+3m$.

Then $a=3m+1, b=3n+1=6m+1, $ and $c=3p+1=18m^2+9m+1$,

so $ \dfrac{2ac}{a+c}=\dfrac{2(3m+1)(18m^2+9m+1)}{18m^2+12m+2}=\dfrac{ 18m^2+9m+1}{3m+1}=6m+1=b.$

This works for any $n$,

so there are infinitely many $3$-term subsequences $(a,b,c)$ of $1,4,7,\dots$ in harmonic progression.

Comment: your solution is simple and good. But how did you come up with special conditions like $n=2m$ and $p=6m^2+3m$. What was your motivation behind it??

Comment: I came up with it by making a spreadsheet with columns labeled $a=1,4,7,\dots$ and rows labeled $c=1,4,7,\dots$ and filled the grid with $b:=2ac/(a+c)$ and found the following integers in the grid:  $(a,b,c)=(4,7,28), (7,13,91), (10,19,190),\dots$; there are others not of the same pattern, such as $(10,16,40)$, but those sufficed to prove the point, and I saw the pattern $(a,b,c)=(3m+1,6m+1,(3m+1)(6m+1))$.  Where did you see this question?

Comment: It's from RMO(Regional Mathematical Olympiad) in India

Comment: I liked it (+1)